# g++ command line macro define byte stream

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, g++, sh

I'm looking for the solution to define a byte stream as a macro from gcc/g++ command line via option -D, e.g. -Dxxx=byte_stream.

Below is the code snippet,

```
#ifndef MAGIC_BYTES
#define MAGIC_BYTES "\x01\x02\x00\x00\xa0\xb0"
#endif
```

I wish every time I can recompile the code without editing the source but using -DMAGIC_BYTES=xxx to define the byte stream.

I know to edit the source could be the solution, but just wonder how to define such byte stream from command line.

UPDATE,

I put the simple code below for this issue,

```
/* When
 * compile: gcc -o macro ./macro.c
 * output: 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5,
 *
 * compile: gcc -o macro -DMAGIC_BYTES=\"\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\" ./macro.c
 * output: 0x78, 0x61, 0x31, 0x78, 0x61, 
 * but I expect 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5
 */
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef MAGIC_BYTES
#define MAGIC_BYTES "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"
#endif

int main()
{
    char buf[] = { MAGIC_BYTES };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%#x, ", buf[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem with the example `-Dxxx=byte_stream` that you gave? This should work out of the box, you might just have to escape the `"` if you want to transmit them into the source. But that again depends on the system/shell where launch your compiler.

Comment: @Jens, the problem is the escape issue. I'm using debian. And when I tried with -DMAGIC_BYTES=\"\x01\x02\", I didn't get the byte stream composed with 2 characters with ASCII code 0x01 and 0x02 if I dump the byte stream in code.

Comment: `char buf[] = MAGIC_BYTES;` because `MAGIC_BYTES` is a string literal.

Comment: @Maxim, true, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this depends a lot from your environment, and the shell that you are using. For `/bin/sh` you could try something like

```
-DMAGIC_BYTES='"\x01\x02"'
```

that is escape the whole string with `''`.

Comment: I tried with -DMAGIC_BYTES='"\x01\x02"', it works for me. If added extra '\' to escape '\', the result is incorrect. Verified on debian/bash. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, changed the answer accordingly